# Confusion on Binding UWP DataGrid to MVVM model

Tags: c#, uwp, xbind

In this [MSDN tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/datagrid_basics) they are using [Model-View-ViewModel [MVVM]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) to bind DataGrid to a list of customers using [{x:Bind} markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) as follows:

```
<controls:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" 
    Height="600" Margin="12"
    AutoGenerateColumns="True"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyViewModel.Customers}" />
```

And they have a `Customer` class as follows:

```
//backing data source in MyViewModel
public class Customer
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public String Address { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsNew { get; set; }

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, 
        String address, Boolean isNew)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
        this.Address = address;
        this.IsNew = isNew; 
    }

    public static List<Customer> Customers()
    {
        return new List<Customer>(new Customer[4] {
            new Customer("A.", "Zero", 
                "12 North Third Street, Apartment 45", 
                false), 
            new Customer("B.", "One", 
                "34 West Fifth Street, Apartment 67", 
                false),
            new Customer("C.", "Two", 
                "56 East Seventh Street, Apartment 89", 
                true),
            new Customer("D.", "Three", 
                "78 South Ninth Street, Apartment 10", 
                true)
        });
    }
}
```

**Question**: Where is `MyViewModel` in that tutorial?

**Remark**: I'm using latest version 6.3.1 of `VS2019`

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial appears to be incomplete.

However, **MyViewModel** could be a public class that would have a `public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers {get; set; }` property.

Example:
MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public class MainPage : ...
{
   public MyViewModel MyViewModel { get; set; } = new MyViewModel();

   public MainPage()
   {        
   }
}

public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; set;} = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
}
```

Comment: The [{x:Bind} markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) does not seem to use `DataContext` or `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Please see the sections `x:Bind & Binding Default behavior` and  `x:Bind and INotifyPropertyChanged` of [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1218367/UWP-Binding-vs-XBind) article.

Comment: @nam: it's true that because {x:Bind} requires a strongly-typed source (i.e. known at compile-time) that it doesn't use `DataContext`, but instead uses the top-level container element as the source. But, other than that it has all of the most commonly-used features that {Binding} does, including responding to `INotifyPropertyChanged`, provided you change from the default mode of one-time to some other mode. The codeproject.com article you link to is shockingly misleading.

Answer (score 0):

> Where is MyViewModel in that tutorial?

`MyViewModel` is supposed to be a property of `MainPage.xaml.cs` that returns an instance of a class that has a `Customers` property that returns an `IEnumerable<Customer>`.

> The `{x:Bind}` markup extension does not seem to use DataContext or INotifyPropertyChanged

It's true that it doesn't use a `DataContext` but generates code that gets a value from the source property, and set it on the target property specified in markup. This is faster than resolving the binding paths using reflection at runtime.

`INotifyPropertyChanged` and the notification of property changes still applies to `{x:Bind}` though.